# What LEGO set is this? White pieces, brick separator, and blue pilot Clone Trooper?

Tags: set-identification

I can't identify this.  What does this build?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minifigure  is  [501st Clone Pilot (75004)](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?M=sw439&in=S)

So it should be this set

[Z-95 Headhunter](https://brickset.com/sets/75004-1/Z-95-Headhunter)
[image]